# HOSTED CHECKOUT obtener detalles de tarjeta evopaymentsmexico

Tags: javascript, php

Soy nueva en la integracion de motores de pago. La documentacion de mastercard evopeyment es algo confusa de momento para mi. Asi que estoy requiendo el apoyo de alguien de ustedes que de favor me pueda resolver mi duda.... ¿Quisiera saber como obtener los detalles de la tarjeta del pagador con los que se efectuo el pago, la hora, el numero de tarjeta etc?

Comment: ¿Estás segura que puedes obtener esos datos? Me llama la atención que desees obtener el número de la tarjeta, los sistemas de pago en línea no te permiten acceder a este dato. Tu aplicación sólo tendrá acceso a un token que identifica a la tarjeta, pero no su número, fecha de expiración ni mucho menos el código CVV. Dependiendo de la plataforma, podrás ver los primeros o los últimos dígitos de la tarjeta, pero no más de eso. Tal vez estás buscando hacer algo que no se puede y por ello la documentación te parece confusa, ya que no hay forma de hacerlo. Saludos

Comment: Bueno no conocer en si esos datos pero si obtener una manera de identificar esa información como por ejemplo el token que mencionas. Saludos